# Arrays JOptionPane version

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

can anyone help me with this.
the assignment is to use JOptionPane in arrays. the user will input the length of the array. then at the end of the program, it will display the largest number.
here is what i got so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class array 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
String L;
int lenght;
L=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"enter lenght: ");
lenght=Integer.parseInt(L);

int[]num = new int[lenght];

for(int counter = 0; counter < lenght ;counter++)
    {


    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"enter #: "+(counter+0));  
int max=num[0];

         if (num[counter] > max) 
         {

            max = num[counter];
         }

    }

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"the largest number is: " + max);
}

}
```

then there is this error:
error: cannot find symbol

Comment: there are a lot of errors in that algorithm..

Comment: sorry for the errors. im just a begginer in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max`is defined in scope of `for` loop. So it is not available outside of `for`.

Define it outside of the `for` loop and it should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String L;
    int lenght;
    L = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter lenght: ");
    lenght = Integer.parseInt(L);

    int[] num = new int[lenght];
    int max=0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < lenght; counter++) {

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter #: " + (counter + 0));
        max = num[0];

        if (num[counter] > max) {

            max = num[counter];
        }

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the largest number is: " + max);
}
```

Update:

You never store the input value to `num[counter]`

```
num[counter] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter #: " + (counter + 0)));
```

Comment: i tried it. the error was gone but no matter how big the numbers i put, it always say that the largest number is 0 even though i did not put it.

Answer (score 0):

```
package retedunits;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class RentedUnits {
private Integer TOTAL_NUMBER_RENT_UNITS; //Total number of rented units
private Double rentPerUnit; //Rent Per Unit
private Double maintainancePerUnit; //Average Maintainance cost per unit
private Integer currentUnitsRented; //Number of units currently occupied
private Double rentIncreaseFactor; //The level at which people leave

//PROFIT MAX
private Double maxRentForProfit;
private Integer maxUnitsForProfit;

public RentedUnits(Integer totalUnits, Double initalRentPerUnit, Double initialMaintainanceCost, Integer currentRented, Double rentIncreaseFactor){

    this.TOTAL_NUMBER_RENT_UNITS = totalUnits;
    this.rentPerUnit = initalRentPerUnit;
    this.maintainancePerUnit = initialMaintainanceCost;
    this.currentUnitsRented = currentRented;
    this.rentIncreaseFactor = rentIncreaseFactor;
}

public Double getMaxRentForProfit() {
    return maxRentForProfit;
}

public Integer getMaxUnitsForProfit() {
    return maxUnitsForProfit;
}


private void increaseRent(Double increasedRent){
    //For each $40 increase in rent one unit is vacant.
    if(increasedRent > this.rentIncreaseFactor) {
        //The number of units that will become vacant is one for every increase of rentIncreaseFactor
        int numberVacate = (int) (increasedRent % this.rentIncreaseFactor);
        this.currentUnitsRented -= numberVacate;
        this.rentPerUnit += increasedRent;
    }
    else {
        this.rentPerUnit += increasedRent;
    }
}

private Double calculateProfit(){

    //Calculate total rent collected from units that are rented
    Double totalRent = this.currentUnitsRented * this.rentPerUnit;

    //calculate the maintainanec of all units
    Double totalMaintainence = this.TOTAL_NUMBER_RENT_UNITS * this.maintainancePerUnit;

    return totalRent - totalMaintainence;
}

public void maximizeProfit(){
    /*Keep increasing rent, and let people leave till the total collected 
    * rent keeps increasing.
    */

    /* Assume you begin at all units occupied*/
    Double maximumProfit = 0.0;
    Double maxProfitRent = 0.0;
    Integer maxProfitUnits = 0;

    /* Keep increasing rent till all people leave while tracking max profit*/
    while(this.currentUnitsRented == 0){
        increaseRent(this.rentIncreaseFactor);
        if(this.calculateProfit() > maximumProfit){
            maximumProfit = this.calculateProfit();
            maxProfitRent = this.rentPerUnit;
            maxProfitUnits = this.currentUnitsRented;
        }
    }

    this.maxRentForProfit= maxProfitRent;
    this.maxUnitsForProfit = maxProfitUnits;
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RentedUnits rentedUnits = new RentedUnits(50, 600.0, 27.0, 50, 40.0);
    rentedUnits.maximizeProfit();
    System.out.println(rentedUnits.getMaxUnitsForProfit() + " units needs to be rented at " + rentedUnits.getMaxRentForProfit() + " rent per unit to get maximum profit.");

}
```

}